# Array is failing to output one row too early

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm working on a code for a "C++ for scientists an engineers" course. We are halfway through the book. I've been looking through the forums and found lots of help there. Thank you all for this amazing resource. I'd like to pose my first question to the group for analysis.

The goal of the project was to

1. create a 60row by 7column array.
2. it must be able to take 4 grades per student, give them a simple average, and a weighted average.
3. output the grades and averages.

I put together everything, its NEARLY complete.  I got a little ambitious when I saw that even if you only input 6 students worth of grades it outputs 60 lines of 0's.  I finally got it to stop printing grades if there were zeros, but now it stops printing one line short.

Example, if I enter 5 students worth of grades it only outputs up to the 4th student and drops the 5th. Once I fix this problem I'm done. I'll add a switch statement allowing the instructor to view HIS wanted initial inputs or to run my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int grade_Calc(int sg[][5]); //initiates function grade_Calc
const int MAXROWS = 60;
const int MAXCOLS = 5;
int grades [MAXROWS][MAXCOLS];
int i,j;
char answer;

int main()
{
////////ENTER VALUES/GRADES/////
i=1;                                            //ROW LOOP
while (i<MAXROWS)
{
    grades [i][0] = i;
    cout << "Please enter 4 grades for student: " << grades [i][0] << endl;
    // COLUMN LOOP
    for (j=1; j<MAXCOLS; j++)
    {
        cout << "Grade: " << j << " is: ";
        cin >> grades [i][j];
    }
    /////enter another grade?/////

    cout << "Would you like to enter another grade? " << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter N for no or Y for yes. " << endl << "Y or NO : ";
    cin >> answer;
    cout << endl;
    if (answer == 'N' || answer == 'n')
        break;
    else if (answer == 'Y' || answer =='y')
        i++;
}


grade_Calc(grades); //passes array grades into function grade_Calc
return 0;
}


int grade_Calc(int sg[][5])
{
int avg_sum = 0;                                                //initializes avg_sum
double grades_weight = 0.0;                                     //initializes grades_weight
double avg_simp = 0.0;                                          //initializes avg_simp


cout << "Stdnt" << "\t" << "Grd1" << "\t" << "Grd2" << "\t" << "Grd3" << "\t" << "Grd4" << "\t" << "Avg1" << "\t" << "Avg2" << endl;                                                        //outputs column headings
for (int i = 1; i < MAXROWS; i++)                           //array rows
{
    if (grades [i][j] <= 0)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < MAXCOLS; j++)                                   // array columns
        {
            cout << grades[i][j] << "\t\t";                                 //outputs array

            if (j != 0)                                             //ignores student number
            {
                avg_sum += grades[i][j];                                    //adds grades for mean

                if ((j == 1) || (j == 4))                               //if-else that calculates grades_weight
                {
                    grades_weight += (0.2 * grades [i][j]);
                }
                else
                {
                    grades_weight += (0.3 * grades [i][j]);
                }
            }
        }

        avg_simp = (avg_sum / 4.0); //calculates simple_avg (arithmetic mean)



        cout << "\t" << avg_simp << "\t" << grades_weight; //outputs simple_avg in Avg1 column and weighted_grade in Avg2 column

        avg_sum = 0;
        grades_weight = 0.0;
        cout << endl;
        }
    }



    return 0;


}
```

Comment: If you have to store 5 students, why do you start loops on 1? the number of elements accessed is last-first+1, which in your case is 4-1+1=4 (last element accessed is index 4, since 5 is already out of the loop).

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are zero indexed in C++.

Change your start to i=0;

Also within your iteration:

```
for (j=1; j<MAXCOLS; j++)
```

j should start at 0 as well.

(Continue with this logic throughout your code... Looks like there are a few places more.)

Answer (score 0):

Your outer loop in `grade_Calc` uses global `j` which is not zeroed after entering grades so it's equal to `5`.

The check in the outer loop passes until the last row, because `grades[i][5]` gives you the first value of next row (it really triggers undefined behavior but in this particular case it appears to be *working fine*). In the last iteration that value is `0` so it breaks before printing.

Change:

```
for (int j = 0; j < MAXCOLS; j++)
```

to:

```
for (; j < MAXCOLS; j++)
```

and put:

```
int j = 0;
```

as a first line in the outer loop so:

```
for (int i = 1; i < MAXROWS; i++)
{
    int j = 0;
    //...
}
```

There are other problems with your code:

1. You have global and local `i` and `j` - your code uses local in one place and global in the other. Get rid of that global variables and declare `i` and `j` locally in the functions
2. you use regular arrays instead of `std::vector` - in C++ you should almost always use `std::vector` instead of array.
3. You are indexing your arrays from `1` - there is absolutely no need to do that.
4. `grade_Calc` doesn't calculate the grades, it calculates avarage and outputs data to the screen. You could split those into at least two different functions.
5. Generally variable names could be much better as all these abbreviations are hard to read.
6. Code should be self-documenting. There should be no need to comment every line.
7. A lot of *magic numbers* - when someone else reads your code he doesn't know why it's `4.0` or `0.2` or whatever without digging into the logic of your program.